# Angular JS : Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am trting to read a json file through Angular's built-in services called $http.But, the page gives me an error saying "Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load *respective json file*".

**Here's my code:**

***angularExample.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Fino">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="FinController as fin">

  <ul ng-repeat="emp in fin.employees" >
  <li>Name:{{emp.name}}</li>
  <li>Age:{{emp.age}}</li> 
  </ul> 

  </body>
</html>
```

***app.js***

```
var app=angular.module("Fino",[]);

app.controller('FinController',['$http',function($http){
    var store=this;
    $http.get('emp.json').success(function(data){
        store.employees=data;
    });
}]);
```

***emp.json***

```
[

            {name:'abc',age:27},
            {name:'bcd',age:24},
            {name:'efg',age:22}
    ];
```

***Error Snapshot:***

[image]

Comment: Please specify the proper URL for the file inside get.

Comment: Aha. You need a webserver ( like apache or http-server if you use node) to serve your files instead of directly trying to access it using file protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Puneetsri said, the best option is to host your files on a web server. Otherwise try launching your app in chrome after starting it with the following flags

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```